# Java - Last created object overwrites previous one

Tags: java, object, overwrite

I am working on a dungeon styled game project and am using a 2D array to create the layout of the rooms. I am using a map generation class and a point class in order to create the map and keep track of which room is being accessed. A starting point is chosen upon generation (usually just 0,0 being the center of the 2D array) and the point for the boss (which is created but not filled). The map generation itself works fine but for some reason my starting point is being overwritten by the boss point. I've tried having the starting point just being defaulted to (0,0) and that didn't work. I tried forcing the boss point to also be (0,0) to start and that resulted in a null pointer exception. I am not sure why this is occurring and would appreciate a bit of help.

MapGeneration Class

```
/**********************************************
 * created by Intellij idea.
 * User: Kyle Castillo
 * Date: 2/14/2020
 * Time: 10:41 AM
 * Contact: kylea.castillo@calbaptist.edu
 ***********************************************/
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;

public class MapGeneration {

    private static Vector<Vector<Integer>> map;
    private Point startPnt;
    private Point bossPoint;
    private static Integer size;

    /************************************************************
     * Constructor class for Map Generation
     * The Size will always be an X by X square based on size
     * Starting Point is specified by the starting (x,y)
     * Rooms are designated by a numerical value
     * - A 0, indicating an empty space
     * - A 1, indicating a filled space with a room
     * - An 8, indicating the array boundary.
     ************************************************************/

    MapGeneration(int size, int startX, int startY) {

        startPnt = new Point(startX,startY);
        bossPoint = new Point();
        MapGeneration.size = size + 2;         //the additional two is to account for boundaries
        map = new Vector<>();

        //Check to prevent the creation of an array where the starting x and y are outside of the array bounds.
        if (startX == 0 || startX == size - 1 || startX == size)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error, the starting X value " + startX + " is not allowed!");
        if (startY == 0 || startY == size - 1 || startY == size)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error, the starting Y value " + startY + " is not allowed!");

        //Creation of the starting room layout.
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            Vector<Integer> tmp = new Vector<>();
            for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
                //The first row, the first value of each row, the last value of each row, and the last row must be 8
                //to prevent the generation later from going out of the 2D array boundary.
                if (row == 0 || col == 0 || row == size - 1 || col == size - 1 ){
                    tmp.add(8);

                    //If the row and col match the starting value then this is the first room.
                } else if (row == startY && col == startX){
                   tmp.add(1);
                } else {
                    //Empty space that can be filled with a room.
                    tmp.add(0);
                }
            }
            map.add(tmp);
        }
    }

    /*********************************************************************************
     * The generate map populates the map based on the desired number of rooms.
     * The number of rooms cannot exceed the maximum space available within the map.
     * If the number of rooms fits then the map is generated from the starting point.
     *********************************************************************************/

    public void generateMap(int numRooms) {
        //Checking to make sure that the number of rooms does not exceed the total number of empty spaces.
        if (numRooms > ((map.size() - 2) * (map.get(0).size() - 2))) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error, room amount exceeds map space!");
        }

        int x = startPnt.getX();
        int y = startPnt.getY();
        Point crntPnt = new Point(x,y);
        bossPoint = crntPnt;

        //Based a random number 0-3 a direction is chosen to create a new room.
        Random randDirection = new Random();
        int compass;
        while (numRooms != 0) {
            compass = randDirection.nextInt(4);
            switch (compass) {
                case 0: //Compass Index is North, indicates a shift in ROW + 1
                    int nextPos = map.get(crntPnt.getY() + 1).get(crntPnt.getX());
                    if(nextPos == 8){
                        //do nothing, its the map boundary
                    }
                    //As long as the next spot isn't already filled, create a room
                    else if (nextPos != 1) {
                        map.get(crntPnt.getY() + 1).set(crntPnt.getX(),1);
                        crntPnt.setY(crntPnt.getY() + 1);
                        //If the current point is further from the start point then make the boss point the current point
                        if (bossPoint.distance(startPnt) < crntPnt.distance(startPnt))
                            bossPoint = crntPnt;
                        numRooms--;
                        //If the next position is 1 move the current position but do not fill the spot or
                        //decrease the number of rooms left to make.
                    } else if (nextPos == 1) {
                        crntPnt.setY(crntPnt.getY() + 1);
                    }
                    break;

                /****************************************
                 * The rest of the cases function the exact
                 * same way as the first.
                 ****************************************/

                case 1: //Compass Index is East, indicates a shift in COL + 1
                    nextPos = map.get(crntPnt.getY()).get(crntPnt.getX() + 1);
                    if(nextPos == 8){
                        //do nothing
                    }
                    if (nextPos != 1) {
                        map.get(crntPnt.getY()).set(crntPnt.getX() + 1,1);
                        crntPnt.setX(crntPnt.getX() + 1);
                        if (bossPoint.distance(startPnt) > crntPnt.distance(startPnt))
                            bossPoint = crntPnt;
                        numRooms--;
                    } else if (nextPos == 1) {
                        crntPnt.setX(crntPnt.getX() + 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2: //Compass Index is South, indicates a shift in ROW - 1
                    nextPos = map.get(crntPnt.getY() - 1).get(crntPnt.getX());
                    if(nextPos == 8){
                        //do nothing
                    }
                    if (nextPos != 1) {
                        map.get(crntPnt.getY() - 1).set(crntPnt.getX(),1);
                        crntPnt.setY(crntPnt.getY() - 1);
                        if (bossPoint.distance(startPnt) > crntPnt.distance(startPnt))
                            bossPoint = crntPnt;
                        numRooms--;
                    } else if (nextPos == 1) {
                        crntPnt.setY(crntPnt.getY() - 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3: //Compass Index is West, indicates a shift in COL - 1
                    nextPos = map.get(crntPnt.getY()).get(crntPnt.getX() - 1);
                    if(nextPos == 8){
                        //do nothing
                    }
                    if (nextPos != 1) {
                        map.get(crntPnt.getY()).set(crntPnt.getX() - 1,1);
                        crntPnt.setX(crntPnt.getX() - 1);
                        if (bossPoint.distance(startPnt) > crntPnt.distance(startPnt))
                            bossPoint = crntPnt;

                        numRooms--;
                    } else if (nextPos == 1) {
                        crntPnt.setX(crntPnt.getX() - 1);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        map.get(bossPoint.getY()).set(bossPoint.getX(),2);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        int sizeTemp = map.get(0).size();
        for (int row = 0; row < sizeTemp; row++) {
            System.out.print("[ ");
            for (int col = 0; col < sizeTemp; col++) {
                int type = map.get(row).get(col);
                System.out.print(type + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("]\n");
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapGeneration map = new MapGeneration(11, 5, 5);
        System.out.println("Empty Map:");
        System.out.println(map);
        System.out.println("Starting point prior to map generation: " + map.startPnt);
        map.generateMap(10);
        System.out.println(map);
        System.out.println("The starting room is at " + map.startPnt);
        System.out.println("The boss room is at " + map.bossPoint);
        System.out.println("The distance to the boss room is: " + (int) map.startPnt.distance(map.bossPoint));
    }
}
```

Point Class

```
/**********************************************
 * created by Intellij idea.
 * User: Kyle Castillo
 * Date: 3/4/2020
 * Time: 9:04 AM
 * Contact: kylea.castillo@calbaptist.edu
 ***********************************************/

public class Point {
    private static int x;
    private static int y;

    Point(){
        //default constructor
    }

    Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public static int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static double distance(Point b){
        int bX = b.getX();
        int bY = b.getY();
        return Math.sqrt((Math.pow((bX - getX()),2.0) + Math.pow( bY - getY(), 2.0)));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "(" + getX() + ", " + getY() + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are `Point.x` and `Point.y` static?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your mistake in the code is, `x` and `y` variables are marked static in `Point` class. Then they will be class variables, not instance variables. Eventhough you create a new instance of `Point crntPnt = new Point( x, y )` varibles `x` and `y` does not belong to this particular instance.

Just change the `Point` class as below, and make sure to change the getters and setters as well

```
public class Point {
  private  int x;
  private  int y;


  public  int getX(){
    return x;
  }

  public  int getY(){
    return y;
  }

  public void setX(int x){
    this.x = x;
  }

  public void setY(int y){
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

As a side note, line `map.get( crntPnt.getY() - 1 ).set( crntPnt.getX(), 1 )` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception if the value is `crntPnt.getY()` is 0. So you may want to handle that too.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome and thank you so much for the help. I was a bit stuck on why this wasn't working and changing that fixed everything. Again thank you so much for the help.